# Difference between 'cargo run' and launching .exe files

Tags: rust

I've encountered weird issue during my Rust journey. I'm trying to execute command via rust, eg. "mkdir abc". Im using standard library for that:

```
use std::process::Command;
use whoami;

(...)

let mut command = Command::new("mkdir");
command.arg("abc");

command.current_dir(format!("/Users/{}/Desktop", whoami::username()));
let res = command.status();

match res {
    Ok(a) => println!("done! {}", a),
    Err(e) => println!("err {}", e)
}
```

This code works correctly as long as i use cargo run command.
Code builds successfuly, but running program from .exe file gives me error:

```
no file or directory (os error 2)
```

No matter the location (current_dir), the same error appears.

I was wondering, what's the difference between these two methods od executing my code. And what's the cause of this error.

PS. I use Windows and tried executing as administrator.

EDIT: hardcoded strings for specific command that causes an error

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps this might be of interest https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup/issues/2565

Comment: If you're running on windows then the path `/Users/{}/Desktop` is highly suspicious. Why are you setting the current directory to what looks to be a unix filepath on a windows system? Have you installed rust through WSL?

Comment: @user1937198 installed rust via rustup_init executable from rust org site. Using windows filepath eg. C:\Users\Username\Desktop doesn't change anything.

Comment: Can you reduce this down into a minimal complete example? ie, can you replace the `args[...]` with fixed strings that cause the issue? can you include the exact commands you are running?